# Delete first and last quote mule 3

Tags: mule, mulesoft

I try to delete the quotes around the payload that is incoming from http request, so I can use it as request for an another call (mule 3).

I use the next transformation syntax;

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

---
(payload.value.id) joinBy " or id eq "
```

and I get this as payload;

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://test.service.com/services/repo/v1/odata/$metadata#Incident",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "7001fc4a-8c8d-43f5-abc7-666666cbdd63",
            "createDate": "2022-01-24T16:47:22Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "ff8aeb42-210c-49d7-aa25-12da825b6b89",
            "createDate": "2022-01-24T19:35:06Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve only the Id's and add id eq or see below.

how ever my desire output need to be like this;

```
9001fc4a-8c8d-43f5-abc7-146945cbdd63 id eq or
ff8aeb42-210c-49d7-aa25-19da825b6b89 id eq or
88eb39ee-d8f7-462c-9b69-1d4a1e3bf994 id eq or
66af209d-7635-4f51-95fd-204e2faea223 id eq or
5b93cf0d-e397-4cea-914b-3842c3aa0847 id eq or
```

I have tried with replace /["]/ with "" and with alot of connectors only I dont get it done.
In mule 4 it's just changing the to output text/plain and it removes al the quotes only mule 3 not.

Anyone experience with this.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: could you please add your JSon input also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using fetch Id's in new http request call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973573/using-fetch-ids-in-new-http-request-call)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of your previous one.

Comment: @AnuragSharma Thanks for response, i have edited the question. I hoop its more clear now. So what I want is to retrieve all the Ids from the object use these Id to retrieve the objects for these Ids. So basically another HTTP request calls

Comment: @aled You are right i have delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

text/plain is reserved for fixed format in DataWeave for Mule 3. Try setting the output to application/java and the use it.

Comment: thanks for helping, I tried it before it was not working but now it does. Do you know also if it is possible to do foreach on http request call in mule 3. I am doing multiple calls to ODATA service which dont look so handy solution. Thanks again Aled